# How to write a SQL join to retrieve results from second table?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Table 1: id#, name, color

Table 2: id#
```

I would like to get all the results from Table 1 `WHERE color = "green"`. After finding the subset of color 'green' from table 1, I then want to find all the matching id#'s from Table 2.

Essentially getting the set from Table 1 with a color=green that exist in Table 2.

Thanks for help with this query!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is an extremely basic join. You need to review your SQL tutorials, not depend on others to spoon-feed you beginner code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE2
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLE1 WHERE color = 'green');
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Table2_ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.Colour = 'Green'
```

Edit: Just noticed you've updated the question with the column names. I'll let you do the substitution ;)